# Filter list within list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
class Order
{
    public string AccountNumber;
    public string AccountName;
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;       
}

class OrderLine
{
     public string Description;
     public string ProductCode;
     public double Duration;
     public int Quantity;
}
```

What would be the LINQ code to get the list of `Order` objects based upon the following conditions?

1. [Order] AccountNumber is equal to "1234"
2. [OrderLine] Quantity greater than 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ - filter child collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896397/linq-filter-child-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want all records that match both conditions (for *any* satisfactory `OrderLine`, otherwise change to `All()`):

```
public static void IEnumerable<Order> GetQualifying(this IEnumerable<Order> orders, string accountNo, int minQty) {
    return orders.Where(o =>
        o.AccountNumber == accountNo
        && o.OrderLines.Any(ol => ol.Quantity >= minQty);
}
```

**Be careful not to get an off-by-one error** as I have interpreted "minimum quantity" literally.

Also, the `this` syntax is great for writing [extension methods](https://www.dotnetperls.com/extension), which allow you to invoke like this:

```
Order[] orders = //stuff;
Order[] qualifiedOrders = orders.GetQualifying("1234", 9).ToArray();
```

Note that I recommend using as `ToArray()` as soon as you can no longer benefit from [lazy evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-and-lazy-evaluation-in-linq-to-xml), otherwise doing subsequent operations on raw `IEnumerable<>` [will cause reevaluation](https://www.softwire.com/blog/2012/08/13/dont-be-too-lazy-linqs-lazy-evaluation-gotchas/index.html) (read: enumerating the collection again).

Answer (score 0):

You could go with:

```
list.Where(x => x.AccountNumber == "12345" && x.OrderLines.Any(o => o.Quantity > 10));
```

or:

```
list.Where(x => x.AccountNumber == "12345" && x.OrderLines.All(o => o.Quantity > 10));
```

depending on whether you want to retrieve all objects that have an `AccountNumber` of `12345` and any `OrderLine` quantity greater than 10 or if all 
`OrderLine` quantity is greater than 10

Comment: @auomine he has AccountNumber defined as string. You might have to correct that in your code.